# Why's the CSS3 transition property acting funny?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Weird stuff happening here. See this tinkerbin page, if you may: http://tinkerbin.com/UZy6H6q4

Here's the html and css in case you can't see the tinkerbin.

```
<head>
<style>

ul{
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:0; 
  margin:0;
  list-style-type:none; 
  background-color: pink;
  }

  ul a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    }

    li{
            float: left;
            height: 30px;
            line-height: 30px;
            width: 90px;
            margin-right: 5px; 
            background-color:red;
            text-align:center;
            -webkit-transition: all .6s linear;
            }

        #case2 li{
           background: none;
       }

           #case2 li:hover, li:hover{
              background-color: lightblue;
              }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- CASE #1 -->

  <ul id="case1">
    <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
  </ul>

  <!-- CASE #2 -->

  <ul id="case2">
    <a href=""><li>Home</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>About</li></a>
    <a href=""><li>Contact</li></a>
  </ul>
</body>
```

So , the problem:

-the transition doesn't work on CASE #1.
-removing the "background-color" from the li element (as I did on CASE #2) makes it work, but in a weird way - when you take back the cursor from over the li element, before the background color fades back to transparent, it first becomes black.

I've tested doing the usual of having the "a" tag nested inside the li, and not the other way around - works fine, as I, for some reason expected. But since, according to the specs, I can have the "li" wrapped in an "a" tag, then why does it not work. Am I missing something?

Oh, and I'm using Chrome - possibly relevant.

Comment: Can the ul (and ol, for that matter) not have anything other than li as child elements - making the a tag wrapping the li invalid? Might that be messing up the rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

putting li inside a is invalid. If you try validating your html then it won't be validated as it doesn't follow the right markup. 
Anchor tags() are stand-alone tags whereas li's are list tags and they are immediate child elements of ul or ol. Hope this helps. :)

Refer w3schools.com for more info.

Comment: www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-a-element -> The`a` cant wrap `li` elements since they're not flow content.

Answer (score 1):

Put `a` tag inside `li`

check this:
http://tinkerbin.com/5kMLVVKk

Comment: Yes, I know. I had also tested that. My problem is in knowing why, as I have "coded" it, it doesn't work. What's wrong with an `li`  inside an `a`? Is it not possible according to the spec? Does the `li` have to immediately precede the `ul` or `ol` tag? Or is the error completely unrelated to the html? Is it just an undefined error? What's missing me?

Comment: It's wrong to give LI inside an anchor tag because LI is a immediately child of UL. For example if you seen HTML in firefox with the inspect element it's render the structure like this "<a href=""></a><li><a href="">Home</a></li>" & you seen IE also.